# Does optuna.integration.TorchDistributedTrial support multinode optimization?

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed, optuna

### Does `integration.TorchDistributedTrial` support multinode optimization?

I'm using Optuna on a SLURM cluster. Suppose I would like to do a distributed hyperparameter optimization using two nodes with two gpus each. Would submitting a script like [pytorch_distributed_simple.py](https://github.com/optuna/optuna-examples/blob/main/pytorch/pytorch_distributed_simple.py) to multiple nodes yield expected results?

I assume every node would be responsible for executing their own trials (i.e. no nodes share trials) and every gpu on a node is responsible for its own portion of the data, determined by `torch.utils.data.Dataloader`'s `sampler`. Is this assumption correct or are edits needed apart from `TorchDistributedTrial`'s requirement to pass `None` to `objective` calls on ranks other than 0.

I already tried the above, but I'm not sure how to check every node is responsible for distinct trials.

---

[GitHub issues crosspost](https://github.com/optuna/optuna-examples/issues/140)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Optuna *does* allow multiple Optuna processes to do distributed runs. Why wouldn't it :)

Basically, run [pytorch_distributed_simple.py](https://github.com/optuna/optuna-examples/blob/main/pytorch/pytorch_distributed_simple.py) on multiple nodes (I use SLURM for this). Every node is now responsible for its own trial. Trials can use DDP.

My method differs from the provided code in that I use SLURM (different environment variables) and I use sqlite to store study information. Moreover, I use the NCCL backend to initialize process groups, and therefore need to pass a device to `TorchDistributedTrial`.

---

Unrelated, but I also wanted to call MaxTrialsCallback() in every subprocess. To achieve this, I passed the callback to the rank 0 study.optimizer method and call it explicitly in local non-rank 0 processes after the objective call.

Comment: "make sure every subprocess calls the trial.report()"
@siem Is this strictly required? I thought that reporting is only needed if a pruner is used?

Comment: @y.mazari I think this is not needed. I edited my answer [docs Trial.report](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.trial.Trial.html#optuna.trial.Trial.report)